# Ardor/NXT platform on Ubuntu

Tags: ardor

When starting Ardor on Ubuntu, i have an error: "Could not find or load main class nxt.Nxt"

Any help?

Comment: What command are you using to start Ardor?

Comment: ./run-desktop.sh

Answer (score 1):

The run-desktop.sh command must be issued from the Ardor install directory.  The command should do a 'cd' to the install directory at the beginning but it doesn't.  You can either do the 'cd' before issuing the command or add the 'cd' to run-desktop.sh.